# UIScrollview Animation Transition From View To View

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am trying to perform a transition animation whenever a user scrolls on a paginated view, i.e: From **Page 1** to **Page 2**.

[image: Main Representation]

Unfortunately, I've not been able to replicate that.

Attach below is what I've done:

```
class OnboardingParallaxImageView: BaseUIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let allImages = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "onboarding_handshake_icon"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "onboarding_paylinc_icon")]

    var activeCurrentPage = 1

    let bgView: UIImageView = {
        let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "onboard_bg_gradient")
        let view = UIImageView(image: image)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let firstImageView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let secondImageView: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.isHidden = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    var firstImageHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var firstImageWidthAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var secondImageHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var secondImageWidthAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()
        addSubview(bgView)
        addSubview(firstImageView)
        addSubview(secondImageView)

        bgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
        bgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive = true
        bgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        bgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        firstImageWidthAnchor = firstImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor)
        firstImageWidthAnchor?.isActive = true
        firstImageHeightAnchor = firstImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor)
        firstImageHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
        firstImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        firstImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        firstImageView.image = allImages[0]

        secondImageWidthAnchor = secondImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor)
        secondImageWidthAnchor?.isActive = true
        secondImageHeightAnchor = secondImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor)
        secondImageHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
        secondImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        secondImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        secondImageView.image = allImages[1]
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let frameWidth = frame.size.width
        secondImageHeightAnchor?.constant = -(frameWidth - 32)
        secondImageWidthAnchor?.constant = -(frameWidth - 32)
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let offSet = scrollView.contentOffset.x

        let frameWidth = frame.size.width / 2

        let toUseConstant = (CGFloat(abs(offSet)) / frameWidth)

        if activeCurrentPage == 1 {
            if offSet <= 0 {
                firstImageHeightAnchor?.constant = 0
                firstImageWidthAnchor?.constant = 0
                firstImageView.isHidden = false

                secondImageView.isHidden = true
            } else {
                firstImageHeightAnchor?.constant += -(toUseConstant)
                firstImageWidthAnchor?.constant += -(toUseConstant)
                firstImageView.isHidden = false

                secondImageHeightAnchor?.constant += -(toUseConstant)
                secondImageWidthAnchor?.constant += -(toUseConstant)
                secondImageView.isHidden = false
                secondImageView.alpha = toUseConstant
            }
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.activeCurrentPage = scrollView.currentPage
    }
}
```

This is the result of what I've been able to achieve:

[image: Failed Representation]

How can I go about transitioning from A to B without any funny behaviour.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of the code , go through - https://medium.com/@nathangitter/building-fluid-interfaces-ios-swift-9732bb934bf5 will help you more.:)

Comment: @Abubakar Oladeji , Are you able to achieve it perfectly or still need help?

Comment: @ShubhamOjha I still do.

Comment: Okay I am confident to achieve it. Just wait for sometime.

Comment: @AbubakarOladeji Please checkout my answer.

Comment: Refer 

Obj-C -> https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands


Swift 3 -> https://github.com/IFTTT/RazzleDazzle

Swift 4 -> https://github.com/wongzigii/RazzleDazzle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve smooth behaviour is using `UIViewPropertyAnimator`.
Setup the initial values for each image view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firstImageView.image = // your image

        secondImageView.image = // your image
        secondImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
        secondImageView.alpha = 0
    }
```

Then create property animator for each imageView

```
lazy var firstAnimator: UIViewPropertyAnimator = {

// You can play around with the duration, curve, damping ration, timing
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .easeIn, animations: {
            self.firstImageView.image.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
            self.firstImageView.image.alpha = 0
        })

        return animator
    }()
```

and the second one

```
lazy var secondAnimator: UIViewPropertyAnimator = {

        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .easeIn, animations: {
            self.secondImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            self.secondImageView.alpha = 1
        })

        return animator
    }()
```

now on `scrollViewDidScroll` when you have calculated the completed percent just update the animators:

```
firstAnimator.fractionComplete = calculatedPosition
secondAnimator.fractionComplete = calculatedPosition
```

You can apply the same approach for multiple views

Comment: So, I just implemented this. I marked it correct because the code made sense just by looking at it and going through apple's documentation. I came back to add a comment and thank you personally. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a Framework for this instead of reinventing the wheel. Something like [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero) for example.

There as some basic [examples](http://lkzhao.com/2016/12/28/hero.html) to get you started. Essentially this provides you an easy to use option to code transition behavior between two UIViewControllers by defining how each UI-Component should behave base on the transition progress.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it using the keyframe animation on ImageView's frame. But you can also achieve it using the constraint based animation as you tried. Just replace the frames size variations that I have done here with the change in constraint's constants as per your convenience.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView1: UIImageView! //HANDSHAKE image on TOP
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView2: UIImageView! //CREDIT_CARD and PHONE image
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView3: UIImageView! //SINGLE_HAND image


    let minimumFrameSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    let meetingPointFrameSize = CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 150.0)
    let maximumFrameSize  = CGSize(width: 400.0, height: 400.0)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let centerOfImages = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2 , y: self.view.frame.height/2)

        //initial state
        self.imgView1.frame.size = maximumFrameSize
        self.imgView1.alpha = 1.0

        self.imgView2.frame.size = minimumFrameSize
        self.imgView2.alpha = 0.0

        self.imgView3.frame.size = minimumFrameSize
        self.imgView3.alpha = 0.0

        self.imgView1.center = centerOfImages
        self.imgView2.center = centerOfImages
        self.imgView3.center = centerOfImages

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 2.0, options: [UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions.repeat,
            UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions.calculationModeLinear],
                                animations: {

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.imgView1.frame.size = self.meetingPointFrameSize
                self.imgView1.alpha = 0.3
                self.imgView1.center = centerOfImages

                self.imgView2.frame.size = self.meetingPointFrameSize
                self.imgView2.alpha = 0.3
                self.imgView2.center = centerOfImages

                /*image 1 and image 2 meets at certain point where
                  image 1 is decreasing its size and image 2 is increasing its size simultaneously
                 */

            })

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.25, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.imgView1.frame.size = self.minimumFrameSize
                self.imgView1.alpha = 0.0
                self.imgView1.center = centerOfImages

                self.imgView2.frame.size = self.maximumFrameSize
                self.imgView2.alpha = 1.0
                self.imgView2.center = centerOfImages

                /* image 1 has decreased its size to zero and
                   image 2 has increased its size to maximum simultaneously
                 */

            })



                      UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.4, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                            self.imgView2.frame.size = self.maximumFrameSize
                            self.imgView2.alpha = 1.0
                            self.imgView2.center = centerOfImages
                                        /* Hold for a moment
                                         */
                        })



            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.6, relativeDuration: 0.15, animations: {
                self.imgView2.frame.size = self.meetingPointFrameSize
                self.imgView2.alpha = 0.3
                self.imgView2.center = centerOfImages

                self.imgView3.frame.size = self.meetingPointFrameSize
                self.imgView3.alpha = 0.3
                self.imgView3.center = centerOfImages

                /*image 2 and image 3 meets at certain point where
                 image 2 is decreasing its size and image 3 is increasing its size simultaneously
                 */
            })


            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.75, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.imgView2.frame.size = self.minimumFrameSize
                self.imgView2.alpha = 0.0
                self.imgView2.center = centerOfImages

                self.imgView3.frame.size = self.maximumFrameSize
                self.imgView3.alpha = 1.0
                self.imgView3.center = centerOfImages

                /* image 2 has decreased its size to zero and
                   image 3 has increased its size to maximum simultaneously
                 */
            })


        }) { (finished) in
            /*If you have any doubt or need more enhancement or in case you need my project. Feel free to ask me.
             Please ping me on skype/email:
                ojhashubham29@gmail.com
             or connect me on Twitter
                @hearthackman
             */
        }
    }


}
```